# cassandra SQL Query is not executing with order by | Sorting is not working in apache-cassandra SQL

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I am currently experiencing an issue with a query in my xyz database. When I try to execute the query

`select * from table where x='data' order by created_at desc ALLOW FILTERING`,

I am receiving the following error message:

`"InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN."`

I have tried troubleshooting this issue on my own, but have not been able to find a solution. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community on how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a workaround. It states that you can't use ALLOW FILTERING and ORDER BY without specifying a partition key. Given that your statement uses `x='data'`, I'm assuming that x is not the partition key and thus you can't use ORDER BY.